# Performing Segue using code gives shows black screen

Tags: ios, swift2

I am trying to do a segue to another screen using code but it shows me a black screen using Xcode 7 beta 6.
here is my 1st view controller file code

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  Segue through programming
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        presentViewController(secondController(), animated: true) { () -> Void in

        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: what is `secondViewController()`?

Comment: I assume `secondController` is the name of the view controller class of that destination scene. I'd suggest following Cocoa naming conventions and capitalizing the first letter of your class names. By convention, variables start with lowercase letters, but classes start with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will only work if `secondController` programmatically creates its view. If you want to use a storyboard scene (which is far more common), you can do the following:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("foo")
    presentViewController(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

That obviously assumes that you've specified a storyboard identifier for the destination scene.

[image]

Or, you can created a segue between the two scenes in IB by control dragging from the view controller icon at the top of the first scene to the second scene:

[image]

and then give that segue its own storyboard id:

[image]

Then you can invoke the segue programmatically:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("bar", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: i got this error 015-08-30 15:57:36.886 Segue through programming[5051:6711545] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7b6b7ca0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'foo''

Comment: @Alexander - Did you give your destination scene's view controller a storyboard identifier of "foo"? If not, change your code to match whatever storyboard identifier you used.

Comment: On my 2nd view controller that i want to segue to has Storyboard ID of foo but i still get the error

Comment: Double check that "Storyboard ID" for the destination scene is "foo" (no quotes, capitalization matches, no spaces, etc.).

Comment: I think i am using Xcode 7 beta 6 that is why it is not working

Comment: No, it works fine in Xcode 6 beta 6. Just tested it and it works like it always has. There something else going on, but without seeing the project, it's hard to tell.

Comment: here are the links [code](http://imgur.com/uT5BNNk,1aV7orY#1) [storyboard](http://imgur.com/Yw5kCuI)

Comment: Yeah, I believe you, but there's something not immediately obvious going on in your project that is getting in the way. Perhaps create a blank project and try it there and you'll see it works there. But there's something else going on here, because this is a tried and true technique, but it's not obvious what's going wrong in your situation. (E.g. do you have multiple storyboards? have you deleted derived data? have you done "Product" - "Clean"?) Without reproducible example of the problem, I'm not sure I can help further.